# Saving a file from a remote hdfs server to my local computer via zeppelin

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-zeppelin

I have access to a zeppelin notebook which sits on a remote server.
In this notebook I can access files on a remote HDFS cluster.
For example, via this notebook I can see the files in the HDFS (in a folder called /user/zeppelin/, and I can see the files for example by running hadoop fs -ls with the shell interpreter) and there are some files there that I want to transfer to my local computer (a Mac) from which I access the notebook. Is that possible? How can I do that?
These files were created by me using spark code on the notebook.

I'm really new to spark, zeppelin and HDFS. I did not need to install anything to access this notebook.

Thanks